# openerp cannot concatenate 'str' and 'function' object

Tags: python, odoo

```
class marcos_artwork(osv.osv):
    def _check_appraisal_price(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
        record = self.pool.get('appraisal_price')
        if record<0:
            return False
        return True

    """artwork class"""
    _name = 'marcos.artwork'
    _columns = {
        'name': fields.char('Artwork',size=32,required=True),
        'description': fields.char('Description',size=200),
        'appraisal_price': fields.integer('Appraisal price' ),
        'createArtWork': fields.integer('Year of creation'),
        'award': fields.boolean('Award'),
        'barcode': fields.integer('Barcode'),
        'commission': fields.integer('Commission',size=10),
        'author_ids': fields.many2one('marcos.author', 'Author'),
        'typeartwork_ids': fields.many2one('marcos.artwork_type', 'Artwork Type'),
        'owner_ids': fields.many2one('marcos.owner','Owner'),
        'style_ids': fields.many2one('marcos.style','Style'),
        'lots_ids': fields.many2many('marcos.lots','artworks_lots_form_rel','id_artwork','id_lot','Artworks'),
    }
    _defaults = {
        'award': lambda *a: False,
    }

    _sql_constraints = [
        ('name_uniqe', 'unique(name)', 'only equals name!'),
        ('barcode_uniqe', 'unique(barcode)', 'only equals barcode!')
    ]

    _constraints = [(_check_appraisal_price, 'Error: Length must be Positive', ['appraisal_price'])]

marcos_artwork()
```

When I want to install the module, I get shown this error:

```
-cannot concatenate 'str' and 'function' object...
```

My function is for checking that the appraisal price is positive.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Please give us the stacktrace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your price checking won't work this way. the big problem here is the line

```
record = self.pool.get('appraisal_price')
```

that's not correct. `self.pool.get` will get you instances of your "business models" like your `'marcos.artwork'` but you want some field values to check.

in this case you don't even need `self.pool.get`, because you're already on this model and can use `self` instead.

so here is the code you need (you will find so many examples in the addons):

```
def _check_appraisal_price(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
    for artwork in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context):
        if artwork.appraisal_price < 0:
            return False
    return True
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't know this specific framework. but I guess from the code It's some kind of "orm" style class. mapping some behavior to a db/table of some sort. Really hard to tell without the full stacktrace but I believe that the error is that your are passing the `__check_appraisal_price` function as reference and not the result of the function - that would be something like `_check_appraisal_price(arg,arg2, etc)`